# unable to convert yaml string to map with key "NO" in java

Tags: java, rest, yaml

While I am trying to convert yaml string to Map I am getting key change.
YAML File:-

```
---
HK: 
  isp: 
    Airtel: AirtelChennal
  www.enemalta.com: 
    default: defaultEma
    user1: chennal1
  studiodefault: hkDefaultchennal
  country: 
    DK: denmarkChennal
    NO: chennal2
```

Java code:-

```
Yaml yaml= new Yaml();
Map<String,Object> map= (Map<String, Object>) yaml.load(yamlString);
```

output :-

```
{HK={isp={Airtel=AirtelChennal}, www.enemalta.com={default=defaultEma, user1=chennal1}, studiodefault=hkDefaultchennal, country={DK=denmarkChennal, false=chennal2}}}
```

in above output false is replace with "NO", but I need "NO" as it is.

Expected output:-

```
{HK={isp={Airtel=AirtelChennal}, www.enemalta.com={default=defaultEma, user1=chennal1}, studiodefault=hkDefaultchennal, country={DK=denmarkChennal, NO=chennal2}}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this article: http://makandracards.com/makandra/24809-yaml-keys-like-yes-or-no-evaluate-to-true-and-false

> In order to use the strings ‘yes’ and ‘no’ as keys, you need to wrap
>   them with quotes

Comment: it is really working thank you @JP Moresmau , other then that any string is there for similarly like 'yes','no'

Answer (score 0):

You should update your parser to one that conforms to the latest standard (1.2 from 2009!), it seems to be conforming to the [1.1 YAML standard](http://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#id864510). And interpret Yes and No as booleans. [In revision 1.2 booleans](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2803629) should be `true` or `false`.

You can get the same effect by making the `NO` scalar an explicit strings by quoting them with single or double quotes.